# Is $\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^1 \frac{1}{(x-y)^2 (y-z)} dx dy dz$ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

My question is in the title :

How could I prove that

$$ \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^1 \frac{1}{(x-y)^2 (y-z)} \ \text{d}z \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x $$

is finite (if it is) ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Aren't the differentials/limits in the wrong order? Should it not be of the form below? $$\int_{z=a}^{z=b} \int_{y=c}^{y=d} \int_{x=e}^{x=f} f(x,y,z) \text{ d}x \text{ d}y \text{ d}z$$

Comment: Ok, I have edited my first post.

Comment: There is the broad notion of [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) for one-dimensional integrals, but that doesn't work when the singularity isn't isolated; in this case, your singularity is the union of the planes $x=y$ and $y=z$, and it's not clear how any meaningful value can be assigned with a non-isolated singularity like this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go through this work to be able to see it will blow up pretty badly, but it makes things a little more obvious: Let $u = x-y, v = y-z$, and $w = z$. Then, $u+v+w = x$, $v+w = y$, and so the jacobian of this transformation is 
$$
|J| = 
\left|
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
\right|
= 1
$$ 
so that the integral becomes (after determining the new limits)
$$
\int_0 ^{1} \int_{-1} ^{1} \int_{-1} ^{1} \frac{du dv dw}{u^2 v} 
$$
which is not finite.

Answer (score 0):

I think asking if the integral is finite is the wrong question, because it suggests that the integral makes sense as a number in $[-\infty,\infty],$ which it doesn't.

Certainly if we put absolute values on, the integral equals $\infty.$ You can see this just by noting

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|y-z|}\,dz = \infty$$

for each fixed $y.$ Without the absolute values however, we can't even get off the ground. What is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y-z}\,dz $$

even supposed to mean if $y\in [0,1]?$

Comment: Actually there's a perfectly reasonable way of assigning a value (specifically, if I've done my math right, $-\ln(2\min(y, 1-y))$) to your non-absolute value integral, but that only works _because_ the singularity is isolated.